# How do I get rid of the Malwarebytes Premium trial?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

I've used Malwarebytes for years, when wanting to do a scan for viruses. I use the free version, running it manually when I want to. My wife recently performed an AV scan using Malwarebytes when something suspicious was going on with my PC and I wasn't there. Apparently she choose the Premium trial. I don't want the Premium version, so I uninstalled it. I thought that would take care of it.

And I was wrong.

I installed the free version - making **certain** that it was the free version, from MalwareBytes' website. The instant I got into it, it immediately popped up the message, "Your Premium trail expires in 3 days". I do not want this at all.

I'm sure some will say, "Hey, just wait 4 days and its gone." Well, remember what I said about my wife pressing the wrong button when running it? This PC is used by all members of my family - I have to be certain that no one else comes along and selected the "Upgrade Now" button.

So, how do I get rid of this Premium trial for good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following:

> 1. Open Malwarebytes interface
> 2. Click on Settings, and click on ‘My Account’ tab and click ‘Deactivate Premium Trial’

[image]

> 3. When you click ‘Yes,’ Premium trial will be converted to free version, information displayed by My Account tab confirms the following:
>
> > - Edition: Malwarebytes Free
> > - Status: Always free
> > - Expiration date: Never expires.

[Source](http://techdows.com/2014/03/revert-to-malwarebytes-free-from-trial.html)